# Multiple table counts in one query

Tags: mysql

I've done some searching around but I haven't found a clear answer and explanation to my question.

I have 5 tables called table1, table2, table3, table4 and table5 and I want to do `COUNT(*)` on each of the tables to get the number of rows.

Should I try to combine these into one query or use 5 separate queries?  I have always been taught that the least number of queries the better so I am guessing I should try to combine them into one query.

One way of doing it is to use `UNION` but does anyone know what the most efficient way of doing this is and why?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Read this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5089427/sql-server-multiple-queries-or-union

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want a count(*) from each one, then

```
SELECT
   ( SELECT count(*) from table1 ) AS table1,
   ( SELECT count(*) from table2 ) AS table2,
   ( SELECT count(*) from table3 ) AS table3,
   etc...
)
```

would give you those counts as a single row. The DB server would still be running n+1 queries (n tables, 1 parent query) to get those counts, but it'd be the same story if you were using a UNION anyways. The union would produce multiple rows with 1 value in each, v.s. the 1 row with multiple values of the subselect method.

Answer (score 0):

Provided you have read access to this (so rather not on shared hosting where you don’t have your actual own database instance) you could read that info from the [INFORMATION_SCHEMA TABLES](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/tables-table.html) table, that does have a `TABLE_ROWS` column.

(Be aware of what it says for InnoDB tables there – so if you don’t you MyISAM and need the precise counts, the other answer has the better solution.)